# ERRCONNRESET Error with OpenVidu hosted in Ubuntu Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, webrtc, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean, kurento

I have implemented **OpenVidu** as given in the **openvidu-js-node** tutorial. I hosted it on Ubuntu Digital Ocean. I am able to log in with the default users but when I try to join a video session I get an error in the NodeJS terminal which says **ERRCONNRESET**. Whereas I am not getting this error when trying the same code in localhost. My server uses https with trusted certificates.

Comment: Do you realize, how abstract your description is ? There is no code/ config file, no error log , no investigative information/trace attached by you,  with which readers can proceed to help.

Comment: this is a very common error. the error log contains nothing except this error in a json format